# WP Menu - insert image next to li on dropdown

Tags: php, html, css, wordpress, drop-down-menu

I want to add a single image into a drop down menu right of the sub-menu items something like what is shown in this image:

[image: add image to menu as shown]

The parent menu is

```
<li id="menu-item-286"</li>
```

Here is the code for my main nav:

```
    <!-- main nav   -->
        <nav class="primary-nav-container">
            <button class="primary-nav-button"><img src="<?php echo get_template_directory_uri(); ?>/images/menu-icon-large.png" alt="<?php esc_attr_e( 'Toggle Navigation', 'minimize' ); ?>" /><?php _e( 'Navigation', 'minimize' ); ?></button>

            <?php
                wp_nav_menu( array(
                    'theme_location' => 'primary_nav',
                    'container' => false,
                    'menu_class' => 'primary-nav menu',
                    'menu_id' => 'primary-nav',
                    'fallback_cb' => 'sds_primary_menu_fallback'
                ) );
            ?>
        </nav>
```

I hope this makes sense, I appreciate any help with this

Thank you

Comment: what have you done so far? you want the image part of the submenu?

Comment: I haven't done anything yet I'm not sure how to achieve this, Yes I want it to show up on the right next to the sub menu items

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I just ended up using ul:after{content:url(image-path);}
and positioning it appropriately.